# Methods of stopping a PHP function being executed at desired state

Tags: php

I have this. Just wondering instead of `exit;` is there another method to stop the function being executed after the echo?

In my situation the reason why I can't use the `exit;` is, if I do so echo takes place in a different window and I need to hit browser's back button to return to the original page. But if I remove `exit;` the message is printed on the same page, however not the specific but all the messages in the array are getting printed on screen as per the sequence.

So what solution can you suggest?

```
    <?php
$directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$max_file_size = 3500000; // size in bytes

if(isset($_POST['submitForm']))
{
    if(!isset($_POST['chkOne']))
    {$ErrMsg = 'Tick the check box if you wish to upload images!';} 
    else{
    /*-------START------- */

$directory_self = str_replace(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$uploadsDirectory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $directory_self . 'uploaded_files/';
$uploadForm = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'index.php';
$uploadSuccess = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $directory_self . 'upload.success.php';

$fieldname = 'file';

    function error($error, $location, $seconds = 5)
    {

        echo '<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"'."\n".
        '"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">'."\n\n".
        '<html lang="en">'."\n".
        '   <head>'."\n".
        '       <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">'."\n\n".
        '       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">'."\n\n".
        '   <title>Upload error</title>'."\n\n".
        '   </head>'."\n\n".
        '   <body>'."\n\n".
        '   <div id="Upload">'."\n\n".
        '       <h1>Upload failure</h1>'."\n\n".
        '       <p>An error has occured: '."\n\n".
        '       <span class="red">' . $error . '...</span>'."\n\n".
        '       The upload form is reloading</p>'."\n\n".
        '    </div>'."\n\n".
        '</html>';

    } 
    $errors = array(1 => 'php.ini max file size exceeded', 
                    2 => 'html form max file size exceeded', 
                    3 => 'file upload was only partial', 
                    4 => 'no file was attached');

// check the upload form was actually submitted else print form
isset($_POST['submitForm'])
    or error('the upload form is neaded', $uploadForm);

// some code //

$now = time();
while(file_exists($uploadFilename = $uploadsDirectory.$now.'-'.$_FILES[$fieldname]['name']))
{
    $now++;
}
$ErrMsg = "<b>Congratulations! Your file upload was successful</b>";

    /*-------END------- */
        }
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
       <form id="Upload" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
           <table name="loadertable" width="394" border="1">
            <td>Upload image :</td>
              <td>
                    <div id="upload_title_text"><input type="checkbox" name="chkOne" id="chkOne">Upload these images:</div>
                    <div id="FileUploadDiv" DivValue="0">
                    <input id="file" type="file" name="file">
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" value="0" id="counter" name="counter">
                    <div align='left'></div>
        <p>
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max_file_size ?>">
        </p>
              </td>
              <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td><input id="submitForm" type="submit" name="submitForm" value="Preview"></td>
              </tr>
            <tr>
             <td><?php if(!empty($ErrMsg)) echo $ErrMsg; ?></td>
            </tr>
          </table>

        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you need to show more of your code. For example, how are you printing the errors? And why does the message show in a different window if you remove it?

Comment: Have you tried die? http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php

Comment: @AdamBrown yup tried die. it does the same job as exit!.. and doesn't work

Comment: @putvande my code is a lengthy one. What do u suggest, shall I put the whole thing here?

Comment: No, rather the bit that is relevant to the problem.

Comment: Especially the bit where you use the function, and how it is returned to the page.

Comment: @putvande and Jason I've updated a part of my code. Pls have a look. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try [*`return`*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php)ing. Quoting the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php):

> If called from within a function, the `return` statement immediately
>   ends execution of the current function

So, basically, instead of `exit;` use `return false;`.

Throwing [exceptions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) could be even better depending on the case.

Comment: In my case this doesn't work either. Is there a possibility than having an echo inside the function, get the echoing values to a variable in some sort and display later?